# how to remove distance between rows in table in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i use 2 box in section 3 in crystal report. but in run time, between rows, show space.!
[image]

titles in box1, and result info in the box2.in box2, for every rows, between rows ,is made space.
how to remove distance between rows in table in crystal report?

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing in report : Right click on section and suppress or set fit to section option.
Your report should be like this.
[image: Report]

Comment: Capture the screen shot of your sections in design view, and update the existing picture. It will make more people answer your question

Comment: Remove space below field or below horizontal line from detail section. Also make sure that you should suppress the sections.

Comment: i can't remove space below field from detail section.how do i do?

Comment: There is a space between your footer and row. Remove it.

Comment: i can't remove space between footer and row.how do i can this?

Comment: i  want , height of row is less

Comment: Implement your report as per my screen. It will set the row height properly.

Comment: how to decrease height of section?

Comment: Right click on your section and click on suppress. It will automatically set your height.

Comment: when click suppress, this row is hidden. i don't want this

Comment: Refer this link [crystal-reports-set-row-height](http://dotnetgoutham.blogspot.in/2012/02/crystal-reports-set-row-height.html)